# google maps api MarkerManager?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I just can't understand why this simple example of MarkerManager shows no marker.  I am opening a map at a center point and then adding one marker to the marker manager.  When the map initializes there is no marker.

What am I missing?

Thanks, Rick

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markermanager/src/markermanager.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map;
        var mgr;

        function initialize() {
            center = new google.maps.LatLng(40.1352891590710, -105.1035852680550)
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 18,
                center: center,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
            mgr = new MarkerManager(map);
            google.maps.event.addListener(mgr, 'loaded', function () {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: center,
                    title: 'marker'
                });
                mgr.addMarker(marker);
                mgr.refresh();
                mgr.show();
                alert(mgr.getMarkerCount(18));
            });
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</head>
<body>    
    <div id="map_canvas" style="height: 800px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markermanager/1.0/docs/reference.html) tells me that addMarker takes two arguments:

```
addMarker(marker:Marker, minZoom:Number, opt_maxZoom:Number) | None | Add a single marker to the map.
```

change the call in your code to:

```
mgr.addMarker(marker, 0);
```